# How can I get the n closest to zero values in a pandas Series?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, series

How can I get the `n` closest values to `0` similar to how I get the n smallest with `nsmallest()`. E.g. with

```py
series = pd.Series([-1.0,-0.75,-0.5,-0.25,0.25,0.5,0.75,1.0])
series

0   -1.00
1   -0.75
2   -0.50
3   -0.25
4    0.25
5    0.50
6    0.75
7    1.00
dtype: float64
```

With e.g. `n=4` I'd like to get the following. The

```
0   -0.25
1   0.25
2   -0.50
3   0.50
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.abs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.abs.html) with [`Series.argsort`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.argsort.html) for positions, filter `n` and select by [`Series.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.iloc.html) if performance is important:

```
n = 4
series = series.iloc[series.abs().argsort()[:n]]
print (series)
3   -0.25
4    0.25
2   -0.50
5    0.50
dtype: float64
```

Last if need default index:

```
n = 4
series = series.iloc[series.abs().argsort()[:n]].reset_index(drop=True)
print (series)
0   -0.25
1    0.25
2   -0.50
3    0.50
dtype: float64
```

**Performance**:

```
series = pd.Series([-1.0,-0.75,-0.5,-0.25,0.25,0.5,0.75,1.0] * 10000)

n = 4000
series = series.iloc[series.abs().argsort()[:n]]
print (series)

In [114]: %timeit series.iloc[series.abs().argsort()[:n]]
794 µs ± 19.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [115]: %timeit series.loc[series.abs().nsmallest(n).index]
2.09 ms ± 34.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: I like the `series.abs().nsmallest(4)` approach of Erfan better.

Comment: @thinwybk - OK, only be carefull for duplicated index, then Erfan solution failed.

Answer (score 3):

Using `loc`, `abs` and `nsmallest`:

```
series.loc[series.abs().nsmallest(4).index]

3   -0.25
4    0.25
2   -0.50
5    0.50
dtype: float64
```